# Copy command postgres append to csv file

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a COPY command in psycopg2 which I am running in a loop. I wanted to know how can I append to CSV rather than performing fresh copy everytime.

code:

```
while True:

    cur.execute("COPY (SELECT id,a,b,c,d from t1,t2 WHERE date>= TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP %(t)s AND date < TIMESTAMP %(t)s + interval '1h' * t2.frequency) \
           TO 'path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;", d)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you update your question with the section of code in question?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Updated the question. It's a pretty generic question of appending to csv file when copy command is being used in a loop.

Comment: I don't recall `COPY` being able to append; however, since you are already using Python, why not just combine all the outputs into a single file after?

Comment: Do you mean opening the file in append mode and then applying the "Copy" command?

Comment: No. `COPY` each individual file then concatenate them into one file using Python.

Comment: Thanks! but I actually wanted it real time.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ugly hack (only works on unix)

```
COPY table_one(id)
TO PROGRAM 'cat - >/tmp/onetwo.out'
        ;

COPY table_two(id)
TO PROGRAM 'cat - >>/tmp/onetwo.out'
        ;
```

Comment: I didn't try this. What does it do? Can you explain it? I understand that the filename's path is /tmp/onetwo.out. Why do you have single > in first line and >> in second line?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html The copy command can read/write from/to a program's stdout/stdin, instead of a file. (This assumes unix, I don't know if windows has usable pipes yet)

Comment: The `>` redirects a program's output to a file. The `>>` does too, but *appends* to the file. The `cat -` program simply copies it's stdin to stdout.